# How to fail test gracefully for any error

Tags: nightwatch.js

Suppose the test fails due to an error from some other library or some service fails, Nightwatch seem to not care about such situation and doesn't fail gracefully leaving behind hanging selenium session. Also, the xml report is not generated.
This is not reported on TeamCity as a failure.

Is there a config item which I can set or do something my own to take care of such exceptions?